# Navigation title / item disappears on switching tab bar item in action sheet clickedButtonAtIndex?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm really pulling my hair out over this one.

I'm showing an action sheet on the first view controller within my first tab bar item, when I tap OK, I'm switching to another view within another tab bar item, using the following code.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
                             clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  {

          self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

*(I assign view controllers to a navigation controller, then to a tab within my app delegate, repeating the process for each tab).*

On return from second tab, when I tap tab item one the **title and info button has gone**.

If I go to next view in the navigation stack within the first tab and back, the title returns.

Here's my first view, I'm about to tap the info buttons.

[image]

This shows an action sheet

[image]

Yes I do need all though buttons, tap on the second one

[image]

OK, it switched me to the second tab.
Now I tap tab one.

[image]

All my navigation items are gone!!!

I've also tried adding a label as a title using...

```
self.navigationItem.titleView
```

However this is lost too.

My theory here is that in my action sheet clickedButtonAtIndex event (where I've running selectedIndex), the event isn't finishing correctly before it switches to the next tab.

Here's the scenario

Any suggestions ?

Since this is such a complex problem I have created a 
[sample project](http://www.kidsmaskfactory.com/code/TabBug.zip).

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem with your sample project. - You can try using `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` instead of `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.

Comment: so now tell me that what was the real problem..

Comment: didDismissWithButtonIndex solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this [sample code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77219201/TestTabSwitchAlertBug.zip)...  and then run. I don't have such problem